# Dealing with a mutable counter variable in closure

Tags: rust

I have written a program to visit directories which is based
on the example on this [page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html).

When I compile it, the compile displays the following 'note':

previous borrow of `file_counter` occurs here due to use in closure;

How can I display file_counter's value?

Is there a better (ie, more functional-like) way to count displayed files, in this program,
perhaps a non-mutable variable and/or recursion?

Many thanks.

```
fn main() {
    let mut file_counter = 0i;
    let display_path_closure = |path: &Path| {
            file_counter += 1;
            println!("{}) path = {}", file_counter, path.display());
        };
    let path = Path::new("z:/abc");
    let _ = match visit_dirs(&path, display_path_closure) {
        Err(e) => println!("error: {}", e),
        Ok(_) => println!("Counter: {}", file_counter)
    };
}

fn visit_dirs(dir: &Path, cb: |&Path|) -> io::IoResult<()> {

    if dir.is_dir() {
        let contents = try!(fs::readdir(dir));
        for entry in contents.iter() {
            if entry.is_dir() {
                try!(visit_dirs(entry, |p| cb(p)));
             } else {
                cb(entry);
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    } else {
        Err(io::standard_error(io::InvalidInput))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by slight restructuring, putting the closure into an inner block:

```
fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("z:/abc");

    let mut file_counter = 0i;

    let result = {
        let display_path_closure = |path: &Path| {
            file_counter += 1;
            println!("{}) path = {}", file_counter, path.display());
        };
        visit_dirs(&path, display_path_closure)
    };

    let _ = match result {
        Err(e) => println!("error: {}", e),
        Ok(_) => println!("Counter: {}", file_counter)
    };
}
```

As for why it happens, it is because closure captures all its environment by unique reference (mutable in your case), as if it is declared like this (pretending for a moment that closures capture their environment by value; in fact that's how unboxed closures work):

```
let mut file_counter = 0i;
let file_counter_ref = &mut file_counter;
// file_counter_ref is a plain pointer so it is copied into the closure,
// not taken by reference itself
let display_path_closure = |path: &Path| {
    *file_counter_ref += 1;
    println!("{}) path = {}", *file_counter_ref, path.display());
};
```

So `file_counter_ref` reference lasts to the end of the block in which closure is defined. In your case it is the whole `main` function starting from the closure declaration. I agree, this may be surprising and I certainly would also think that closure environment borrows die with the closure (e.g. when the closure is moved into the function and this function returns), but that's how things are now.

The situation with closures in Rust is currently unstable: unboxed closures have just been added to the language, so old boxed closures (like the one in this example) will soon go away; moreover, borrow checker is [also being improved](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2ecg69/work_starting_on_nonlexical_lifetimes/). These features may interact in complex ways, so maybe your original example will become possible soon :) (just a speculation, of course)